# Partition not showing in debian

Tags: debian

I decided to switch to debian xfce 64 bit . I used the live cd for testing it. I have a 20gb ntfs, 30 gb ntfs,25 gb ext4 and swap partitions
I can see the 30gb volume but I cannot see my 20 gb ntfs partition in it. parted /dev/sda then print shows all of my partitions. But I did not see it at the file manager. Lmde shows the 20 gb partition. Do I have to update any drivers or any other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can view ALL partitions is to use a partition editor, as you did with `parted`. I’m going to assume you used a file manager like Thunar on your Debian Xfce; the problem is that Debian doesn’t mount your NTFS partition automatically like LMDE does: it’s just not configured to do that. All file managers only can see mounted partitions. It is best to use either the front end to `parted` (GParted, which is standard on most Debian-based distros) or to use `fdisk` or `gdisk`, depending on your needs. If you only need to see your partition table, `lsblk` does the job just fine by displaying a tree of all the partitions detected.

Comment: I do not have any problem with the other 30 gb ntfs partition. Only the 20 gb ntfs partition is not shown. It is not a problem with thunar because if there were any problems then my 30 gb ntfs partition must not be displayed.

Comment: @karthikeyan - As this answer states, the file manager only shows _mounted_ partitions. The 30g partition being visible shows that your system is _capable_ of mounting NTFS partitions, but the 20g partition still won't show up unless some process has actually mounted it.

Comment: If you want to view mounted partitions on a liveCD, that is possible from the terminal using mount /dev/sdXY /mnt or a similar command. You can find more info by using man mount.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the windows partition was not mounted automatically like the rest. Debian interpreted /dev/sda1 as its / partition and tried to mount it as ext4. This solution was useful.